# When a class is loaded in java for every .class file separate Class Type object is created why?

Tags: java

In a java program, when a class is loaded into the method area the Class type object is created in the heap area. Questions:

1. If 10 `.class` files are loaded then 10 Class type objects are created right?
2. What is the purpose of creating the Class type object for every `.class` file by JVM?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many many reasons. Like: you want to write code such as:

```
Class<Foo> fooClass = Foo.class;
Annotation[] annotations = fooClass.getAnnotations();
```

Meaning: the class Class enables you to programmatically inspect (reflect) on your types. Or to use reflection to invoke constructors or methods based on raw strings.

And of course: the JVM itself needs all kinds of information about the classes it knows. So it makes perfect sense to "collect" all that information right at the point when the class is loaded.

Imagine you are a shop owner, and you decide to carry a new item. One of the things to do: update your internal inventory that lists all items, and maybe describes the attributes/properties that matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

After loading a .class file, JVM will create an object of the type java.lang.Class in the Heap area. We can use this class object to get Class level information. It is widely used in Reflection.

Source : `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-class-in-java/`

Comment: developer can get the class level data and for reflection Class type object is used. assume developer does not want the class level information and developer is not going to use the reflection

now what is the purpose of class class object 

normally In software industry if are using reflection if and only if we do not have a solution

Comment: @MasithPrasanga And? As written in my answer: the JVM itself needs all kinds of information about the structure of classes, which methods are in and so on. Class objects being available to the user is a positive side effect. The main purpose is here is that the JVM has a standard way of representing that information, and having it available right after a class was loaded.

Comment: @GhostCat when a class is loaded into the method area, these are the information store in the method area

    1). fully qualified name of the classs
    2). fully qualified name of the immediate parent
    3). method information
    4). constructor information
    5). variable information and so on,

then why we need class class object to store those information again

Comment: @MasithPrasanga I suggest you study the APIs of the class loader. Loading a class means always results in **creating** a Class object. That is simply the design point of the JVM. class file bytes ... turn into a Class object. That decision was made like with java 1. Sure, theoretically, maybe, you don't need to keep those around. On the other hand: why design for that very special use case?

Comment: @GhostCat I know class loading means always results in creating a Class class object, I have mentioned it in both problem heading and description as well, if you say decision was made like with java 1.0V, why is that decision, as you mentioned why design for that very special use case

Answer (score 0):

I believe this part is handled by JVM's ClassLoader system.
Except the first class of main(), ClassLoader system creates class type objects statically if new is triggered or dynamically if Class.forName() is used. In Object oriented concept class type object is reference to the class.

Comment: I believe your answer is not precise enough. The class loader loads classes when needed (for example when getting used by other classes). **Part** of loading a class is to create that Class object. The class object is available long before you do a potential new() call for example.